# extract data column-wise from text file using regex

Tags: regex

I have a text file like

```
27/02/2017 17:59:39 562803 299060 235155

27/02/2017 17:59:44 562803 299058 235158

27/02/2017 17:59:49 562803 299057 235158

27/02/2017 17:59:54 562803 299057 235158
```

I want to extract data from a particular column using regex.  Which  expression will extract the 3rd column?

Comment: what P-language you are referring it to?

Comment: Hi Ankit, if you could add what approach you have taken prior to posting the question that would be great :)

Comment: I have to use it in xml. so i want regex expression. Some thing like              [\s]+(\d+). this is for extracting the last column. I want to extract specific column say 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Linux, `awk` is the best utility for this

```
awk '{print $3}' file
```

awk divides a file into fields, usually separated by tabs or whitespace. `$3` represents the third column or field.

Another good utility is `cut`

```
cut -d " " -f3 file
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want regex expression for extracting the column.

Comment: It's still best to use awk